# Implementing Carousel with PageViewer in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a carousel (the kind with the dots on the bottom to show the number of items / pages and the current selected item) using `PageViewer`.

The swipe part is working fine, but the indication that there a further content available was missing.

I tried using `PagerTabStrip` and `PagerTitleStrip` but they are showing the page title, but I want to show the dots.

I have read about a few libraries which provide the functionality but am trying to avoid using those.

Please let me know if there is a way I can extend my current code to accommodate it

**EDIT**

the updated layout code is as follows

`

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_graph_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.vivekji.munimji.activity.TabGraph">

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" android:background="#fff"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use [CirclePageIndicator](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator) along with [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

**1. Add gradle dependency**

```
    dependencies {
       compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    }
```

**2. Use CircleIndicator in your layout**

```
   <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"/>
```

**3.Set up indicator with viewpager**

```
ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
viewpager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
indicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
```

Comment: I tried the same but does not seem to be doing anything :( the code is as follows `<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp" android:background="#fff"/>`

activity code
`CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
  indicator.setViewPager(vp);
  vp.setAdapter(pa);`

Comment: Please post layout file